# please help fixing my portugese sauce (a kind of korma-like non-spicy curry sauce served in hk and macau)

Tags: curry

The original recipe generally advise on pan-frying the sauce with oil. I want to avoid that and still make it taste good  by just putting everything in a pressure cooker...

Here is the everything in my recipe when first put in pressure cooker for 20 minutes:

a carrot (cut by food processor)
two small or 1 big potatoes (cut by food processor)
one small or half a big onion (cut by food processor)
a big block of curry roux  (equivalent to 2-3 small block of curry roux)
a teaspoon of salt
a teaspoon of sugar
5 teaspoons of chicken consomme
200ml yogurt
1.5 teaspoon of tumeric
1 cup of water
(coconut milk made by putting 5 table spoon of coconut fine and half a cup of water in a mixer)

After 20 minutes, I stir the mixture and add 0.5 cup of water and cook for another 15 mintues.

After 15 minutes, I stir the mixture and add another 0.5 cup of water depending on how thick the mixture is.

The result is not satisfactory. I try adding a can of cream of corn soup from campell. It does not help.

Any recommendation would be welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly is wrong with the result?

Comment: I'm voting to close as the question needs detail on what the actual problem is, and it also has no detail on the original recipe or method.

Comment: @GdD - I kind of agree, but as this is a 'traditional sauce' the OP's divergence from an 'optimal' recipe can be reasonably guessed from the recipe we have so far.

Comment: I think you are making too many assumptions @Tetsujin, we can't guess what the poster doesn't like about the result.

Comment: @GdD - I may be, but the recipe & method as posted is going to be like pish, compared to what it should be ;-)) It's like saying, "I made an omelette, with one egg & half a pint of water."

Comment: Plus a can of cream of corn soup @Tetsujin ;)

Comment: @GdD - desperate times presumably called for desperate measures ;) OK, this current batch is in no way recoverable [other than by considerable dilution in a lot of new batch], but for next time…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, though you need to clarify - not 'rich' enough & probably thin in both flavour & texture, with a grainy edge.

Yoghurt adds acid, rehydrated coconut is absolutely no substitute for coconut cream.

Rehydrated coconut won't provide either the flavour or the texture of coconut cream. It will leave the sauce thin yet slightly 'gritty'.

Yoghurt is going to add an acid edge that this sauce doesn't need.

Pressure-cooking rather than frying off in an open pan then allowing to simmer will keep too much liquid level in the sauce, exacerbating both the above points.

Once you've corrected those, if you want 'more curry but no more heat' then try adding some garam masala.
I'd also add garlic & a little light soy sauce.

If you're not having this with the traditional chicken, then you're also missing the ingredients the chicken would have been marinated in - soy, shaoxing, ginger - so maybe some of those too.

You're also missing the oil that the frying would have added, but if you don't want to add that, the coconut cream will have to be the only fatty mouth-feel ingredient. Lose all the fat, lose the mouth-feel of the sauce, I'm afraid.
You could cut the coconut cream to coconut milk, but I think that would still come out too 'skinny' in taste & texture.

Personally, I'd double the curry roux, but I just like more kick than traditional in this type of sauce ;) It will help the texture, though.